# Read every line in a file then save every line as an accessible string

Tags: python

So I'm reading every line with this code:

```py
with open ('file.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
```

but I want to save every line as a global accessible string. Any way I can do that?

Comment: you can append each line into a list. First, define an empty list `l = []` before the with statement. Then, use `l.append(line)` inside the for loop. Then, you can print the list or if you want to get each string in the list, just do a for loop on the list.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "save every line as a Global accessible string"?

Answer (score 1):

Contents of example file `foo.txt` :

```
Hello there
```

---

Program :

```py
def can_we_read_it():
    print("Here is the contents:")
    print(foo)


def get_text(*args, **kwargs) -> str:
    with open(*args, **kwargs) as file:
        return file.read()


foo = get_text("foo.txt", "r") # foo is available in the global scope,
                               # it contents 'Hello there' as a string
can_we_read_it()
```

---

Content streamed to `stdout` :

```
Here is the contents:
Hello there
```

Ie, we have the string available in the global scope as we have assigned it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to store file content in accessible string variable is by using this 2 lines of code:

```
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as file
    content = file.read()
```

If you want to get a list of lines this is the code that you need:

```
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as file
    content = file.readlines()
```